# Display Grouped List Web Part as Tiles

Tags: 2010, web-part, list-view, custom-list

I'm creating a Sharepoint Site in SP 2010 to hold information for Meetings at my Company. This site will hold documents and will need them to be grouped by **Meeting Type** and then by **Meeting Date**.

I've accomplished this grouping via a List Web part but I do not like any of the built in "Styles" for this Web Part. I'm looking to group things similar to an Application called Directors Desk as shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to do this within Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a couple of options

**Data View Web Part (DVWP)** - if you can use SharePoint Designer at your firm you can use a DVWP to apply custom presentation to a list. With some XSLT ninja skills you can get quite creative and get very far from the standard list view. [Start here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-data-view-HA010094804.aspx) for the basics.

**Custom web part using EMCAScript Client Object Model** - basically a javascript interface into your list then use your own javascript display logic - perhaps mixing in the best of jQuery for presentation. You could start by examining my [SPrello project on codeplex](http://sprello.codeplex.com/) which will give you a head start in using the client object model and jQuery to display list items in tiles.

**'Traditional' Custom web part using server side object model** - similar to above but rather than everything being client side javascript its all server c#/vb.net. [Start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231579.aspx)